# いくつになったら in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-の

いくつになったら買ってくれるの？

I'm not sure of the grammar used in this sentence.

いくつ-> Does this still refer to how many?

になった->Is the なった here a conjugation of なる (To become)?

Also is the の at the end of the sentence the contraction of an explanatory の (e.g. the written form of んです)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that this sentence is used in a context where a child asks his mother/father to buy him something, yet the parent said no, due to the child being too young.

If translated directly, it would be something like "If I become how old, will you buy it for me?"

いくつ can be translated as "how many" or "how old", and in this case, I used "how old".

Omitting the details, なったら is a form of なった, which can be thought as a past-tense of なる。

About the terminal の, I don't know the correct grammatical explanation, but it adds the sense of questioning.

Comment: "When will you buy it for me when I grow up?"

Comment: @snailboat OK, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

> いくつになったら買ってくれるの？

- How old do I have to be before you will buy it for me?
- How long do I have to wait before you'd buy it for me?
  How much more do I have to wait before you'd get it for  me?
  How many more years do  I have to wait until I can finally get it?

About the terminal の？, it's probably short for のですか？

In the last few years, this ending has become common on the Net :

> 買ってくれるん？

-- which is short for -- 買ってくれるんですか？

There's also a [relative tense] issue. 
 Please see:  [相対テンス -- ①ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買う。　②ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買った。　③ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買う。 ④ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買った。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39648/16344)