# 相対テンス -- ①ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買う。　②ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買った。　③ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買う。 ④ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買った。

Tags: tense, aspect, past, future, relative-tense

http://blog.livedoor.jp/robinsonrobin/archives/8036910.html

1. ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買う。
2. ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買った。
3. ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買う。
4. ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買った。

If I completely understand these, will I have undertood half of all the complex issues in Jp [relative tense] (相対テンス) ?

<sub>( but before we can get to that, we first have to understand these 4 sentences. )</sub>

What is a reasonable description of a "complete understanding" of these 4 sentences?  I think it should at the very least include these:

(A). giving a simplified explanation to distinguish the 4 sentences.

(B). giving the biggest problems with that simplified explanation.

Could someone answer A and B ?

---

A. -- Here's the simplified explanation.  If a speaker says (1-4) in Japan --

- 買う。 means the speaker hasn't bought the hat. 　買った。 means the speaker has.
- 行く時、 means buying the hat in Japan.  行った時 means buying the hat in Hawaii.

This is good as a 1st approximation. However, . . . see responses to B.

---

B. -- Thank you for bringing up Mr. Niwa's page :

> ... されている http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/48toki.html のキャッシュ
>
> 主節が過去の場合、よく例に出されるのは次の２つの文の違いです。
>
> タイへ行く時に、タイ語を少し習った。（日本で） 
> 　　　　　タイへ行った時に、タイ語を少し習った。（タイで）
>
> 上の二つの文は、「どこで習ったのか」という違いがはっきりあります。　
> 「行く時」では「まだ行っていない」ので、タイではなく、ふつうは日本で習い、「行った時」では「もうタイにいる」ので、タイで習った、となると説明します。

I think that in both of these sample sentences, studying of the Thai language could've been in Japan or in Thailand.

タイへ行った時に、タイ語を少し習った。 <---
Esp. in this second example.  If this happened a long time ago (like 10 years ago), there is almost no sense of ordering (study then travel *OR* travel then study) expressed in this sentence.  Do you agree?

Comment: What is the question? After reading your "question" I really wonder whether you've read the link you provided. Or may be you want a generalization on "how relative tenses work in general" (which is quite broad)

Comment: Yes, the link provides an answer to A (in Jp). 
_____ (but the Jp answer isn't very well-written, and  a good Eng.-lang summary may be of great use and interest to ppl here.) 
_____ So my main interest is in B.

Comment: You can see a more in depth explanation here ( http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/48toki.html ) (enc: EUC-JP)

Comment: @HizHa I recommend the pair of books 『初級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック』 and 『中上級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック』. Can you see this chapter at Google Books?  https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=0eprLex8sr0C&pg=PA68

Answer (score 2):

タイへ行く時に、タイ語を少し習った。
When going to Thailand, I studied a little of Thai.
Because 行く refers either to the present or future, it means that I studied Thai BEFORE going to Thailand.

タイへ行った時に、タイ語を少し習った。
When I went to Thailand,  I studied a little of Thai.
This has the exact same meaning as in English. I went to Thailand, THEN I studied Thai.

Answer (score 0):

Variations of :  私が作った料理を一口食べるなり、父は変な顔をした。 [Why 食べるなり rather than 食べたなり?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39677/16344)

> 1. 私が作った料理を食べる時、父は変な顔をした。
> 2. 私が作った料理を食べた時、父は変な顔をした。

1 could be past habit, or one-time event --  maybe closer to the beginning  of the meal.

2 doesn't sound like past habit.  It could be (1) after one bite, (2) closer to the end of the meal, or (3) some event in the past.

> 3. 私が作った料理を食べる時、父は変な顔をする。
> 4. 私が作った料理を食べた時、父は変な顔をする。

These are recurring events. (habit)

3 is closer to the beginning  of the meal.

4 could mean (1) after one bite, or (2) closer to the end of the meal.