# What does いくつになっても exactly mean?

Tags: expressions, pronouns

> **いくつになっても**「いい子」が上手いな!

A is angry at B for being kind to somebody and says that. They are both young adults.

It should mean "No matter the age, you are good at being a good boy!", but I don't understand the logic of いくつ. I need a more literal translation, word by word.

I've found [いくつになったら](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27307/%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-in-this-sentence), it's similar, but it's a question, mine is not.

Can you say どこになっても, 誰になっても, 何になっても and so on too, when you're not asking a question? If so, can you make some examples with other pronouns too, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- いくつ can mean "how old" by itself. It should be explained in any Japanese-English dictionary.
- `interrogative + ても/でも` is a basic pattern to say "wherever", "no matter who/what/how", etc.

  - [Maggie Sensei: Wh-ever/No matter wh/how: ても/でも ( = temo/demo)](https://maggiesensei.com/2016/10/12/wh-everno-matter-whhow-%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-temodemo/)
  - [【JLPT N3 Grammar】Question word + 〜ても](https://nihongo-net.com/2019/08/29/jlptn3-question-temo/)
- This (～に)なる is a simple verb that means "to turn (age)". For example, 5歳になる means "to turn 5". It's not part of a special construction in this case.

Therefore, いくつになっても straightforwardly means "no matter how old (someone) gets".

Likewise, 誰になっても can mean "whoever you become" (e.g., in a context of shapeshifting) or "no matter who is chosen" (e.g., in a context of election).